# ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (SMTP)

Tags: python, sockets, networking, smtp

I am trying to send an test email from one gmail account to another using SMTP socket. I have allowed unsecure access from my client gmail account.

During the login phase the code breaks here:

```
#Send username as Base64 encoded string
username = (username + '\r\n').encode()
command = base64.b64encode(username)
clientSocket.send(command)
resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print('S: ' + resp.decode())
```

I am getting the 10054 error message and have tried using wireshark to decompose whats happening, but I am not really understanding whats happening. It seems to be an server side encryption based off google smtp server. I am new to socket programming, thanks for your patience!

The rest of the code:

```
from socket import *
import time
import base64

print("")

username = input("Enter your mail.com username : ")
password = input("Enter your mail.com password : ")
rec = input("\nEnter the recipient's email address : ")
name = input("\nEnter your name : ")
subject = input("\nEnter the subject for your mail : \n")

message = ["SMTP client is awesome \r\n", "123456789 \r\n","Networking is cool. \r\n"]

print("")

endmsg = "\r\n.\r\n"

# Choose a mail server (e.g. Google mail server) and call it mailserver
mailserver = "smtp.gmail.com"
mailserverPort = 587

# Create socket called clientSocket and establish a TCP connection with mailserver
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((mailserver, mailserverPort))

resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print('S: ' + resp.decode())

# Send EHLO (for Extended SMTP) command and print server response.
heloCommand = 'EHLO 127.0.0.1 \r\n'
print('C: ' + heloCommand)
clientSocket.send(heloCommand.encode())
resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print('S: ' + resp.decode())

# Authentication start mail server client
command = 'STARTTLS \r\n'
print('C: ' + command)
clientSocket.send(command.encode())
resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print('S: ' + resp.decode())

# Authentication required for the mail.com server I'm using
command = 'AUTH LOGIN \r\n'
print('C: ' + command)
clientSocket.send(command.encode())
resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print('S: ' + resp.decode())

# Send username as Base64 encoded string
username = (username + '\r\n').encode()
command = base64.b64encode(username)
#print('C: ' + command.decode())
clientSocket.send(command)
resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print('S: ' + resp.decode())

# Send password as Base64 encoded string
password = (password + '\r\n').encode()
command = base64.b64encode(password)
print('C: ' + command)
clientSocket.send(command)
resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print('S: ' + resp.decode())

# Send MAIL FROM command and print server response.
command = "MAIL FROM: <" + username + ">\r\n"
print('C: ' + command)
clientSocket.send(command)
resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print('S: ' + resp.decode())

# Send RCPT TO command and print(server resp.decode()onse.
command = "RCPT TO: <" + rec + ">\r\n"
print('C: ' + command)
clientSocket.send(command)
resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print('S: ' + resp.decode())

# Send DATA command and print server response.
command = "DATA\r\n"
print('C: ' + command)
clientSocket.send(command)
resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print('S: ' + resp.decode())

# Send message headers
# Gmail does not accept mail without headers to prevent spam
command = 'From: ' + name + ' <' + username + '>' + '\r\n'
print('C: ' + command)
clientSocket.send(command)
command = 'To: ' + rec + '\r\n'
print('C: ' + command)
clientSocket.send(command)
command = 'Date: ' + time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) ) + '\r\n'
print('C: ' + command)
clientSocket.send(command)
command = 'Subject: ' + subject + '\r\n'
print('C: ' + command)
clientSocket.send(command)

# Send message data.
clientSocket.send('\r\n')
for msg in message:
    print('C: ' + msg)
    clientSocket.send(msg)

# Message ends with a single period.
print('C: ' + endmsg)
clientSocket.send(endmsg)

# Send QUIT command and get server resp.decode()onse.
command = "QUIT\r\n"
print('C: ' + command)
clientSocket.send(command)
resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print('S: ' + resp.decode())
```

Answer (score 0):

The `STARTTLS` command requests an SSL/TLS encrypted session to be initiated.  But there is no SSL/TLS logic in your code at all.  If the server replies success to `STARTTLS`, your client MUST initiate and complete a successful SSL/TLS handshake before it can then send any further SMTP commands.  Those commands (and their responses) are required to be encrypted by the SSL/TLS session.

You are getting forcibly disconnected because you are not following the protocol.  So either don't use `STARTTLS` (in which case, your `AUTH` will likely fail), or else implement SSL/TLS properly on your socket.

And BTW, you SHOULD NOT enable "unsecure access" to your Gmail account. Have Gmail create an [application-specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) and use that instead of your real password.